# Work with database in classes

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I´m wondering how to work with database in classes. For example how to write queries for easy future edit and by OOP rules.

First example:

```
    class User {

    public function select($query) {
        //work with data
        return $data;
    }

    public function insert($query) {
        //work with data
    }
}
```

In this example user (me) add queries for each method. For me, big disadvantage is that I must remember correct form of my query. This example is easy to understand, but in case I will work with more complex queries, it would hard to write correct form of query.

Next example:

```
class User {

    const select = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = ?";
    const insert = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (?)";

    public function select($id) {
        //work with data
        return $data;
    }

    public function insert($id) {
        //work with data
    }
}
```

I defined each query as contstant. This form of class is very handy but on the other hand if I want to get ID of user I can't, because I would know name of ID field in the database. This problem I solve in third example

Third example:

```
class User {

    private $table, $idField;

    public function setDatabaseInformation($table, $idField) {
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->idField = $idField;
    }

    public function select($id) {
        //work with data
        //query as SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE $this->idField = ?
        return $data;
    }

    public function insert($id) {
        //query as INSERT INTO $this->table VALUES (?)";
        //work with data
    }

}
```

Personaly I think, this example is the best, because there I have everything what I want and I can't rememeber forms of queries. On the other hand, this example is a bit longer, very universal and I don't know it is correct by OOP rules.

My questions are: Is there any other options how to write queries in database? Is the last example correct by OOP rules? Which way do you use?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Why you don't use an ORM like Doctrine?

Comment: I have never worked with ORM or framework :) Is it necessary?

Comment: If you want to work with objects then you should use an object relationel mapper and don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: Your question is way too broad to be answered here. May I suggest looking at [IdiORM](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)/[Paris](https://github.com/j4mie/paris) instead? It's quite simple to grasp yet very powerful - at least for simple queries. )

Comment: Use an ORM and save yourself a lot of hassle and BUGS!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I should read something about ORM in case it is better and  necessary.

Comment: look into querydsl as well. It avoids writing sql queries as strings. Also it adds a bit of type safety into your sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Abstract* the whole thing inside the class! You want to write code which looks like this in the end:

```
$database    = new PDO(...); // or whatever
$userStorage = new UserStorage($database);

$user  = $userStorage->getById(42);
$users = $userStorage->getByName('Joe');

class UserStorage {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getById($id) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT ... WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        ...
        return $user;
    }

    ...

}
```

You only want to write each logical query once in one specific, authoritative place. For each possible logical "action", create a method (one method to get users by id, one to get them by name, etc.). Each method can be as complex or simple as necessary internally, but it is the one place where you write the specific query to get the specific data. Lastly: dependency inject your database connection.

Comment: There are frameworks in place now to avoid this type of boilerplate.

Comment: Not sure what the boilerplate is here. If you're working with more complex database structures, now or *in the future*, one logical action may not resolve to just getting data from a single table. Most frameworks map database tables 1:1 to class structures, which I find to be undesirable in the long run. What's wrong with writing each logical thing you want to do with your database in its own canonical method?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from BUT the boilerplate is staring right at you here. It's all the database connection/setup statements etc. The real essence of the logic is the sql query. That's all. Everything else is boilerplate. A good framework hides all that so all you need to do is write the sql query.

Comment: You'd have to show me a concrete example of what you're talking about here. In my experience all database abstractions end up getting on my nerves eventually, because they keep me from doing what I know I want to do. The boilerplate I'm seeing here is just a class constructor, not much more.

Comment: What should I do in case I would like to work with another table?

Comment: @Facedown 1) Why would you want to work with another table? 2) You can still keep the table as a variable which you set on class instantiation. `"SELECT ... FROM $this->table ..."`.

Comment: This way is very handy :) Thanks for you advice.

Comment: One more question. If I want work with another table should I create new class? For example when I will work with table Login, should I create something like LoginStorage? Or just change table variable in constructor.

Comment: @Facedown You should divorce the relationship between database tables and classes that access those tables. Rather think of it in terms of logical things to do in your app. There's one canonical class method to, say, save a new user in the database. There's one canonical method to retrieve a product by id. There's one canonical method for logging someone in. Each of these methods may or may not correspond to one specific table. Maybe some of these methods query more than one table to do what they need to do.